# sphinx-apidoc to identify file types other than .py

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I built a language expansion for Python 3, which allows its users to generate Python files with '.pytsl' suffix. I want to use Sphinx for documenting those files. However, when running
sphinx-apidoc on a specific directory, the '.py' files under that directory get translated to '.rst', while the '.pytsl' files don't.

I searched in the documentation for sphinx-apidoc and in the help section, but couldn't find a way that allows me to enable sphinx-apidoc to identify files with an extension other than '.py'.

Is there a way to do this?
If not, can this be supported?

Comment: Recognized file suffixes are determined by `EXTENSION_SUFFIXES`. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/4.x/sphinx/ext/apidoc.py#L46 and https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES.